Oracle SQL - Pick max of a sequence number
I have a table in oracle database, which contains



user_id
seq_no
act_no




123
1
ABC


123
2
LNM


123
3
THIS


456
1
NOT


456
2
THIS


456
3
ONE


789
1
NOT


789
2
THIS



Expected output



user_id
seq_no
act_no




123
3
THIS


456
3
ONE


789
2
THIS




Use row_number() window function to number each user_id's rows, ordering by seq_no descending. Return the number 1 rows.
select user_id, seq_no, act_no
from (
  select t.*, row_number() over (partition by user_id order by seq_no desc) rn
  from tablename t) dt
where rn = 1

